# вывести простые числа от 1 до n. Пожалуйста подскажите в чем ошибка, не могу разобраться

Tags: javascript

Пожалуйста подскажите в чем ошибка, не могу разобраться

```js
let n = 50,
  count = 0;
let b = false;

for (let i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
  for (let j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
    if (i % j == 0) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  if (count == 2) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21966000/need-to-generate-prime-numbers-in-javascript

Comment: вы забываете обнулить `count` для каждого нового числа в цикле

Comment: @Lexx918 а ее обнулять вначале первого цикла фор?

Comment: @btcfakir да, после первого for и перед вторым

Answer (score 1):

Первый вопрос, а что за count? Просто для вывода она не нужна (может, для того чтобы посчитать количество?..). Ну окей, давай подумаем над алгоритмом:

1) Нам нужно перебрать все числа от 1 до n, с проверкой на простоту. Окей, цикл for для перебора всех чисел в студию! (метка 'outer')

2) Когда a число называется простым? Когда есть такое число `1<b<a`, `a%b=0`. Собственно эта проверка у вас и была, но опять же, зачем count?? Если срабатывает условие, то число явно не простое, и нам нужно продолжить поиск для других a

3) Если таки весь вложенный цикл отработал, и условие не сработало - поздравляю, у нас простое число, давайте напишем об этом!

```js
let n = 50;
let b = false;

outer: for (let i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
  for (let j = 2; j*j <= i; j++) {
    if (i % j == 0) {
      continue outer;
    }
  }
  console.log(i);

}
```

Comment: 1. `i = 1` - неверно, должно быть `i = 2`.
2. `j < i` - верно, но неоптимально - лучше `j*j <= i`.
3. `count = 0` надо было удалить, раз не используешь.
4. Число называется простым, если у него ровно 2 делителя - 1 и оно само. Именно поэтому единица не простая - у неё всего 1 делитель.

Comment: Вот за 1 мне сейчас стыдно.. Спасибо за комментарий! @Qwertiy